# Binary Search Tree traversal, combine InOrder, PreOrder, PostOrder, RevInOrder in a single method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, traversal

I have a binary search tree and have to write a inOrder, preOrder, postOrder and reverseInOrder method, here is my implementation based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) (excluding inOrder):

```
public String reverseInOrder() {

            String retString = "";

            // 1. Traverse the right subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.bigger != null) retString += this.bigger.reverseInOrder() + ", ";

            // 2. Access the data part of the current node.
            retString += this.content;

            // 3. Traverse the left subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.smaller != null) retString += ", " + this.smaller.reverseInOrder();

            return retString;
        }

        public String postOrder() {

            String retString = "";

            // 1. Traverse the left subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.smaller != null) retString += this.smaller.preOrder() + ", ";

            // 2. Traverse the right subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.bigger != null) retString += this.bigger.preOrder() + ", ";

            // 3. Access the data part of the current node.
            retString += this.content;

            return retString;
        }

        public String preOrder() {

            String retString = "";

            // 1. Access the data part of the current node.
            retString += this.content;

            // 2. Traverse the left subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.smaller != null) retString += ", " + this.smaller.preOrder();

            // 3. Traverse the right subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.
            if (this.bigger != null) retString += ", " + this.bigger.preOrder();

            return retString;
        }
```

As you can see, I always do the same three things:

- access smaller subTree
- access current content
- access bigger subTree

Only the order in which I do them changes (ignoring the insertion of commas for readability).
I would therefore like to reduce all types of this method to a single one, where you can choose the order, here is my implementation:

```
    /**
     * ops:
     * 0 := smaller/left
     * 1 := this content
     * 2 := smaller/right
     */
    public String someOrder(int firstOp, int secondOp) {
        List<String> retParts = new ArrayList<String>();

        int thirdOp = 3 - firstOp - secondOp;
        for (int el : new int[]{firstOp, secondOp, thirdOp}) {
            switch (el) {
                case 0:
                    if (this.smaller != null) retParts.add(this.smaller.someOrder(firstOp, secondOp));
                    break;

                case 1:
                    retParts.add(this.content.toString());
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (this.bigger != null) retParts.add(this.bigger.someOrder(firstOp, secondOp));
                    break;

                default:
                    // shouldn't happen
                    break;
            }
        }

        return String.join(", ", retParts);
    }
```

Short try at an explanation:

> You tell the method the order of operations by passing it the first
>   and second operations (e.g. fistOp = 0 if you first want to go into
>   the smaller subTree), the method infers the last operation. In order
>   of the operations, I do what the operation represents. In the end I
>   return results of the operations as a joined String

This doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me though, so I am open for suggestions on how to solve this problem (also in general, how to combine multiple methods which differ in the order of operations in Java)

Comment: If the code is working and you are searching for recommendations to make this all more *"elegant"* then the question probably belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyways, I've already a recommendation for you: Use an `enum` to specify the algorithm. Looks less messy.